# VS code opens the same file every time

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS code keeps only opening 1 project/file even if I try to open another one. It keeps defaulting to the same project. I've tried deleting the file that it keeps opening, but it just gives me an error. I've also tried reinstalling the app as well as resetting all my settings. The only way for me to open a different file is to manually change it in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `restoreWindows` settings to `none`. like this:

```
"window.restoreWindows": "none"
```

Open the settings in your Visual Studio Code settings page. Search for `window.restoreWindows`. Select `none` from the drop down.